# Is defining a class method without visibility a shorthand of 'public'?

Tags: php, visibility

I often see code a function defined without visibility keywords. e.g:

```
class Foo() {
  function bar() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Is it a shorthand of `public` function? Is it a good practice to omit it?

```
class Foo() {
  public function bar() {
    //..
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's public, and imo it's _bad_ practice to omit it. The auto-completion function in IDEs may not recognise the function as public if you do so (NetBeans in particular has problems).

Comment: IMO, it is completely optional.  The only time you really need to specify is if you are following a singleton pattern and you need it to be private.

Comment: I'd include always `public` because I think that a focus on code readability is always a good practice.

Comment: http://php.net/language.oop5.visibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [PHP Doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php),

> Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

So, yes, in

```
class Foo() { public function bar() { //.. } }
```

`Foo::bar()` is public, but omitting the visibility keyword is never a good practice. If it's a fast and ugly script why not, but in other cases you should specify it.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you are right; when you omit the visibility modifier it means it's `public`.

It's a holdover from PHP 4 which did not support visibility operators.  This feature is included for backward compatibility.

You can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: +1 For providing the explanation what this is about so everybody can do it's own decisions.