# Php - Do functions and variables have to be declared public?

Tags: php, encapsulation, public

Do functions and variables have to be declared `public` or are they `public` by default?

```
Class Bread {
    $bread = "";    
    function toast()
    {
        $bread = "Toasticles!"
    }
}
```

In this example, is both `$bread` and the function `toast()` public without actually declaring them as such?

**This is a question about instance variables and function visibility**

Comment: Just do it. This is a shortcut with no benefit.

Comment: [Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods)

Comment: No they don't have to be declared public (otherwise there would be no point in private or protected even existing); they will be public unless you specify otherwise.... but for clarity, it's better to specify

Comment: However, `$bread` with no visibility indicated is a syntax error.

Comment: I get a syntax error if I don't put `public` in front of my instance variable. PHP Version 5.2.4

Comment: [Class properties *must* be defined as public, private, or protected.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-members)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is defining a class method without visibility a shorthand of 'public'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987443/is-defining-a-class-method-without-visibility-a-shorthand-of-public)

Comment: @Don'tPanic that question doesn't ask about variables

Comment: True, perhaps because the person who asked it had already realized that a named property without a visibility keyword was a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare `$bread` without visibility, you **will** get a parse error:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '$bread' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in **[...][...]** on line **x**

This is because, as @darkcrystale also mentioned and as [PHP documentation states](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods), class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.

Function `toast()` will be `public` by default if you do not specify the visibility explicitly.

But please keep in mind, that doing things explicitly is **better**, than doing things implicitly. Thus, declaring visibility as public in every case might help those, who read your code after you. If you don't care about those, who might work with your code (btw shame on you in that case), think of another example: you write a lot of code not declaring visibility explicitly and it's `public` at that time. But if the PHP devs go crazy and change default visibility to `private`, then most of your code becomes useless (and will not work) for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods)

**Properties:**

> Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. **If declared using var**, the property will be defined as public.

**Methods:**

> Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

Comment: Seems dumb. Why make methods default public, but instance variables have to explicitly be declared.

Comment: Good question, I think you should ask it on StackOverflow.